# Are directions available for the maven plugin com.alexnederlof jasperreports-plugin?

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

I have read up on the limited information regarding `com.alexnederlof` `jasperreports-plugin` and I'm looking to convert my current ant build to use this maven plugin, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation available.

My biggest concern is run-time: If I use this plugin at build-time, what version of `jasper-reports` do I need to use at run-time?

Am I missing a reference somewhere? As the old adage goes, "If there isn't any documentation, then I guess I'll have to write it."

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of what you are after but, I am using this plugin in maven to generate the source .jrxml files to .jasper files and the configuration in pom goes like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.alexnederlof</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>  
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jasper</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- These are the default configurations: -->      
        <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler</compiler>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/jasperreports</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</outputDirectory>
        <outputFileExt>.jasper</outputFileExt>
        <xmlValidation>true</xmlValidation>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <numberOfThreads>4</numberOfThreads>
        <failOnMissingSourceDirectory>true</failOnMissingSourceDirectory>
        <sourceScanner>
             org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.util.scan.StaleSourceScanner
        </sourceScanner>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope this helps